# Laravel find model method returns wrong result

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

this code

```
FeesApplies::find(2)->toSql();
```

return this query

```
select * from `fees_applies`
```

Why does it ignore id?

Primary key in table is ok.
When I write

```
FeesApplies::where('id',2);
```

it works ok

Comment: Does `FeesApplies::find(2)` actually return the wrong result? You have a misunderstanding of how the `toSql` works in this particular situation, so I'm trying to figure out if there's an actual issue or just confusion on your part.

Comment: If it *does* give you the wrong result, please print out `FeesApplies::find(2)->toJson()` and see what's being fetched.

Comment: I try to understand why find(id) return wrong result (when I add "_use DB;_" in my model it works ok)

Comment: That really doesn't make any sense and speaks to something *else* wrong in your code. A `use DB;` call wouldn't affect this functionality one bit. Do you have calls in the model/controller using direct `DB` calls?

Comment: Yes.. perheps I changed enything else in code.. but now it works. Ok, thanks for answers

Answer (score 2):

When using `Model::where('id', $value)` syntax, the `where` method will return an object of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.  When using the syntax `Model::find($value)`, the `find` method will return an instance of an Eloquent model.  Models themselves can be used to query the database, but when trying to convert an Eloquent instance directly to SQL without adding any other conditions (or using methods that return a `Builder` object), the instance will default to selecting all records without any conditions.  The following script may help shed a bit of light on what is actually going on in your situation:

```
// $fees1 will be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
$fees1 = FeesApplies::find(2);

// Asking the model instance to convert itself to SQL without any conditions
var_dump($fees1->toSql());

// Asking the model instance to retrieve a Builder object with a single condition
var_dump($fees1->where('id', 2)->toSql());
```

Asking the model instance to query the database again is a  *brand new query*, and not 'building' on your previous one you used to actually retrieve the instance.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the find() correctly. It is easy to accidentally to use first() leading to incorrect result while you code still runs. We just re-factored where() to find() and this was causing the issue:

```
Model::find(1)->first();
```

This may appear to be working but what you actually get is the first row from the table!

Comment: Thanks. Was making the same mistake by using first.

Answer (score 0):

Is it returning wrong results, or is the sql query wrong?
To see the queries ran try

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
FeesApplies::find(2);
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Comment: `find()` returns the record with this id passed, if you are missing a record with id 1 this might be the first record.

Comment: I have record  with this id, but it still returns wrong result. But when I`ve added "use DB;" in my model it works right.   Thank you for your answers